# Android Studio: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I made a CRUD app on Android Studio where I used Room, Dao, LiveData & ViewModel dependencies. But I keep getting this error when I try to run the app:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

I've tried turning off Gradle Toggle-offline mode after reading some answers to similar questions asked before on Stackoverflow, but to no avail.